# Changing state of COM node with changing resistor value in LTspice

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice

I'm trying to isolate two circuits using an op-amp voltage follower circuit with different neutral levels in LTspice.

When the two neutral levels are connected via a 1 MΩ resistor, everything is fine, but when it is changed to 1 GΩ, everything changes and the voltage at the COM port starts to show a significant sinusoidal voltage.

[image]

[image]

1. Could anyone explain what is happening with this circuit?
2. I'm not using a bi-polar supply with the op-amp, what possible problems can that cause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember the idealised model of the op amp:

[image]

Now using the input section of this model, your circuit will turn into something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flTjkj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So, what the op amp will see is the voltage across `Zi`, and the bottom end of `Zi` is basically its reference point. Of course `Zi` can't be infinite in practice (and in simulation, of course) so it'll be quite a large number.

> When the two neutral levels are connected via a 1 MΩ resistor, everything is fine, but when it is changed to 1 GΩ, everything changes and the voltage at the COM port starts to show a significant sinusoidal voltage.

Now it appears that the `Zi` that LTspice uses for the op amp is too large that `RG = 1M` becomes negligible (e.g. `Zi = 1G = 1000 x Zi`). Therefore, for `RG = 1G` the voltage across `Zi` becomes quite large because the division ratio changes significantly.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question.

I want to know one more thing. I'm trying to avoid any significant current flow due to ground looping, so will a 1M resistor be sufficient?

Comment: @Electronics_seekhado_koi impossible to answer. I answered your question using the ideal op amp model in which the input section is shown as an infinite resistance. But practical op amps have transistors so it's hard to adapt the same results to a real world application. The inputs sink (or source) some current from (to) the inputs (this current is called `input bias current`) and the value of this current varies from chip to chip. This will influence the accuracy if the application involves measurement.

Comment: Thanks for the help.